# How to check if objects are not empty

Tags: jsf, el, jsf-1.2, is-empty

I'm trying to check if objects are not empty in a JSF 1.2 view. The expression is:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{deuteBB.detallDeute.estatDomiciliacio ne empty and deuteBB.detallDeute.cccDomiciliacio ne empty}">
```

However, this did not work, neither with `&&` instead of `and`. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your attempt you're basically comparing it to a variable with the name `empty` like so in "plain Java":

```
if (!deuteBB.getDetallDeute().getEstatDomiciliacio().equals(empty) && !deuteBB.getDetallDeute().getCcccDomiciliacio().equals(empty))
```

This is thus definitely not right. The right `empty` operator in EL is a prefix operator and should thus be used like so `#{not empty bean.property}`.

In your particular case, this should do:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty deuteBB.detallDeute.estatDomiciliacio and not empty deuteBB.detallDeute.cccDomiciliacio}">
```